# Android Login with Amazon - did't redirect to app after success Login

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, login-with-amazon

I have implemented "Login with Amazon" in android app.
Everything works fine in android Marshmallow and i can get IdentityID.

**But i am facing problem in android KitKat, the app did't redirect after successfully Login.**

I am using the following snippet to authrize

```
AuthorizationManager.authorize(
                    new AuthorizeRequest.Builder(requestContext)
                    .addScopes(ProfileScope.profile(), ProfileScope.postalCode())
                    .build());
```

**The page load with following error**

> This site can't be reached.

**Note : App works fine with Amazon shopping App, problem occurred in external browser(chrome and default browser)**